# Need answer for this SAS practice question, with explanation if possible

Tags: sas

You’re attempting to read a raw data file and you see the following messages displayed in the SAS Log:

```
NOTE: Invalid data for Salary in line 4 15-23.
RULE:     ----|----10---|----20---|----30---|----40---|----50-
4         120104   F    46#30     11MAY1954 33
Employee_Id=120104 employee_gender=F Salary=. birth_date=-2061 _ERROR_=1 _N_=4
NOTE: 20 records were read from the infile ‘c:employees.dat’.
      The minimum record length was 33.
      The maximum record length was 33.
NOTE: The data set WORK.EMPLOYEES has 20 observations and 4 variables
```

What does it mean?

```
A. A compiler error, triggered by an invalid character for the variable Salary.
B. An execution error, triggered by an invalid character for the variable Salary.
C. The 1st of potentially many errors, this one occurring on the 4th observation.
D. An error on the INPUT statement specification for reading the variable Salary.
```

Comment: Note sure why this has been put on hold. Especially by users with low or zero SAS reputation points.

Comment: This Question ist most likely from the Book SAS Base Programming for SAS 9 at the moment i have no access tom my copy of it but this books also contains an answer section. Also this question is for self-testing regarding the current section. If one could not answer read the section again. If one can't answer it by yourself maybe he has other problems that might hinder one to become SAS programmer. So this question should not answered or it will destroy the whole purpose of this qeustion.

Comment: I suppose the answer is D., but if you try to 'fix' the specification you could end up with 19 NOTEs instead. Since the NOTE: appears in only line 4, of 20, the real error is actually in the data being read, and the input statement not shown is probably ok.  The missing value for salary would be expected from bad data, so not sure if there is an 'ERROR' at all.  Bad question

Comment: Maybe C.  I agree with @Richard bad question.

Comment: Not C because # of obs logged shown -- meaning step is done, and no other NOTES. Of course there potentially could be prior ERRORs/NOTEs above the snippet shown, but I would not place that cardinality in the realm of 'many' .

Comment: @datacode80 - if you are looking for peer-reviewed practice SAS questions that have explanations, try https://sasensei.com

Comment: I think this is on topic, but not a good question.  Just to be clear, 'homework' or 'test prep' questions are fine on Stack Overflow, but they should show the same amount of effort as on other questions: don't just post the question, say why you're asking it and what you think (or what you're confused about).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the problem:

> NOTE: Invalid data for Salary in line 4 15-23.

That is the note you get when you have an input statement from a file or datalines, and you are expecting a numeric value but encounter a nonnumeric value that cannot be read into that field (or otherwise something that doesn't match the expected informat).

> D. An error on the INPUT statement specification for reading the variable Salary.

That seems like the best answer to me, depending on how you parse the answer text.

- (A) refers to compiler errors, which mean they occur before any data is read in - it's certainly not that, data is where the problem is.
- (B) is the other possible answer; it is execution time certainly, and it is indeed caused by an invalid character in the data, but I don't like how that answer is worded and think it's not clear.
- (C) is wrong because this is the only error you see...
- (D) is the most accurate, I believe, if you assume your data is right anyway.  It's possible though that the Input statement is right and your data is bad; in that case it would point to (B) being the right answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help